# How to insert new row in Excel if found specific letter

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to Excel especially in macro vba and I am trying to setup a macro that adds a row above a specific point of the worksheet.

The other example show in loop method which doesn't what i want. I want to inserting new row above a first specific letter but not repetitive. i will show you the example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh8Ad.png)

[image]

Is this possible? How?

Thanks for all the possible help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, See example below

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim i&

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For i = Cells(Rows.Count, ["A"]).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(i - 1, ["A"]) <> Cells(i, ["A"]) Then Rows(i).Insert
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

*To add 2 or more rows use Rows(i).Resize(2).Insert*

---

Helpful links

*[Excel VBA Shortcut Range References](http://blog.excelhero.com/2010/06/05/when_working_in_vba_we/)*

*[Range.Resize Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx)*

---

> <sub>*[Range.Resize Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx) Resizes the specified range. Returns a Range object that represents the resized range.*</sub>